# using a class as a data type in hashmaps

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to use a class instead of String in the HashMap<Integer, String>,
lets say the class name that i will be using is Bids.java.
and a method called  'addBid' that accepts three parameters: buyer ID, bid price, and bid date. This method must create and a new instance of the Bid class and put in the HashMap attribute the <buyerId, bid> pair.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class BidsManager {
    // Interger key and bid value in the hash map as an object for bid maneger class
    HashMap<Integer, Bid > bidHashMap = new HashMap<Integer,Bid>();
    Bid bid;

// a contsuctor that takes zero parameter and initilizes the bit hash map object
    public BidsManager() {
        this.bidHashMap = bidHashMap;
    }
    //add bid method that acceptes buyer ID, bid price and bid date
    public void addBid(int buyerID, double bidPrice, int bidDate){
// here is where i am not sure with how to put the Bid into the HashMap
         bidHashMap.put(buyerID, );

    }

}
```

Comment: First your constructor is useless and to implemente addBid you just have to create a New instance of bid and put into your map bidHashMap.put(buyerID, bid);

Comment: So is your question "How do I create a Bid"? That's all you need to do. You have all the code you need. Just create a Bid and add it as the second argument to put()

Answer (score 0):

Your last sentence states the solution:

> This method must create and a new instance of the Bid class and put in the HashMap attribute the <buyerId, bid> pair.

So you need to perform two steps:

1. Instantiate a `Bid` object.
2. Pass that instance as the *value* argument to the [`Map#put`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#put(K,V)) method.

Code:

```
public void addBid( int buyerID , double bidPrice , int bidDate )
{
    Bid bid = new Bid( buyerID , bidPrice , bidDate ) ;
    this.bidHashMap.put( buyerID , bid ) ;

}
```